# My HTML page becomes unresponsive when doing javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html

My HTML page is having password input field when I try to input values to the password input field then the page becomes unresponsive after entering more than 30 to 40 characters.

I am having this issue in all web browsers. Even if I change the minimum length and all other like lower, upper, number and symbol value to 50 then also the same problem persist. I am new to javascript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Style all input fields */
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the container for inputs */
.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Try to submit the form.</p>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="usrname">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="usrname" name="usrname" required>

    <label for="psw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">199 <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">199 <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">199 <b>number</b></p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>199 characters</b></p>
</div>
    
<script>
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('(?:[a-z].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = new RegExp('(?:[A-Z].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = new RegExp('(?:[0-9].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 199) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add a maximum length not a minimum length (to the input field) ? Why would anyone want a 40-letter password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the snippet and run fine after getting 30-40 characters I'm pretty sure it takes a while to process all your code. That's why in becomes unresponsive (depend on the computer)

to solve it:

1-. Change `onkeyup` to `onchange`. This will limit all your regrex validation just when the person finish writing the password

2-. Change `onkeyup` to `submit` and return true or false if its validated. (I prefer this one. It's kind of annoying that you are taping your password and tells you that it's wrong. "I know, I just start to type it"

here is the code for the second option:

This will only submit the form to the php if the validation return true.

Note: you should change the regex in just 1 line for better performance

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
function validate() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('(?:[a-z].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {  
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }
  
  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = new RegExp('(?:[A-Z].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {  
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
    return false;
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = new RegExp('(?:[0-9].*){' + 199 + '}', 'g')
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {  
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
    return false;
  }
  
  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 199) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```css
/* Style all input fields */
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

/* Style the submit button */
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

/* Style the container for inputs */
.container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */
#message {
  display:none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Add a green text color and a checkmark when the requirements are right */
.valid {
  color: green;
}

.valid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✔";
}

/* Add a red text color and an "x" when the requirements are wrong */
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.invalid:before {
  position: relative;
  left: -35px;
  content: "✖";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p>Try to submit the form.</p>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <label for="usrname">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="usrname" name="usrname" required>

    <label for="psw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="psw" name="psw" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters" required>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="message">
  <h3>Password must contain the following:</h3>
  <p id="letter" class="invalid">199 <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
  <p id="capital" class="invalid">199 <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
  <p id="number" class="invalid">199 <b>number</b></p>
  <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>199 characters</b></p>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your regexes are horribly inefficient. You're doing some weird stuff that I think is making the regex engine try to match all possible combinations of all letters, which is an O(n^2) problem, which means for every additional letter, the processor does double the work.

Here are better regexes:

- Contains lowercase: `[a-z]`
- Contains uppercase: `[A-Z]`
- Contains digit: `\d`

Some other minor performance optimizations you can do:

- Don't modify the DOM unless you have to. You're adding and removing classes every keypress, which is bad. Instead, keep track of whether something is valid using js variables, then only update the DOM if your javascript state doesn't match the DOM state.
- Don't create new regexes on every keypress. Just create them once and reuse them.